# how to insert current date/time in Ms Access using c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, ms-access

I have tried almost everything to insert the current date and time in to MS Access  database using c# and nothing seems to work.
The table structure looks like

```
ID(Primary Key) Est_ID(Number)  saveName(Text) userName(Text) timestamp(Date/Time)
```

The code looks like

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();

DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime time= DateTime.Now;
string name = Request.Form["saveName"];

string my_querry = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (userName, Est_id,saveName,timestamp) VALUES(@userName,@Est_id,@saveName,@timestamp)";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_id", est_index);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saveName", name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestamp",time);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have tried formatting. I added # but nothing seems to work. This is really frustrating since I have spent more than a day now getting this to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it not give you any errors? Normally failed inserts/updates result in errors explaining whats wrong.  At the moment the code you have would complain that timestamp has not been supplied.

Comment: did not work. It gives an error saying select into statement invalid

Comment: @user3342812 You might want to rethink the use of "AddWithValue".  See this: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: What is the name of your table in MS Access?

Comment: TABLENAME is just the placeholder

Comment: Gotcha. If you could include the full error in the post, that'd be helpful.

Comment: Please put your actual code, as your table name maybe relevant!

Answer (score 1):

OleDB/Access requires you to explicitly set the data type for date/time values.

```
var param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestamp",time);
param.OleDbType = OleDbType.Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();

string name = Request.Form["saveName"];

string my_querry = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (userName, Est_id,saveName,timestamp) VALUES(@userName,@Est_id,@saveName,Now())";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_id", est_index);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saveName", name);


cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

According from this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-the-date-and-time-field-in-Access-47fbbdc1-52fa-416a-b8d5-ba24d881b698

You may need to check on your column setting in database that It's already set Format of timestamp column to Genaral Date to match with DateTime.Now in C#.

Also, You need to check that output of System.DateTime and your database time format is 12Hours system or 24Hours system.

Hope this information can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tortuga Chain:

```
static AccessDataSource s_DataSource = new AccessDataSource(connectionString); //one per application
```

---

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime time= DateTime.Now;
string name = Request.Form["saveName"];

s_DataSource.Insert("TABLENAME", new {@username = userName, @Est_id = est_index,@saveName = name,@timestamp = time}).Execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is a little old but it could help someone.
Since this morning I am confronted with this problem. And I finally found the solution.

The value that `DateTime.Now` sends to the database is in the form `{dd / mm / yyyy hh: mm: ss}` and what happens, I think, is that access does not recognize `{ }`.

So to solve the problem just convert the date to string before assigning it to the parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithvalue("@timestamp", time.ToString());
```

Or

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithvalue("@timestamp", oleDbType.Date).Value=time.ToString());
```

That work very well for me